# User Input Concentric Circles

Tags: python, geometry, user-input

I want to create concentric circles. I want the user to input how many circles they would like and at any specified radius. My problem is that the circles are not forming within one another.Any hints would be awesome

```
import turtle
import random
n1 = int(input("How many circles"))
n2 = int(input("Radius?"))
for i in range(n1):
   turtle.penup()
   turtle.right(50)
   turtle.forward(i)
   turtle.begin_fill()
   turtle.color(random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
   turtle.circle(n2)
   turtle.end_fill()
   turtle.pendown()
   turtle.home()
while i in range(n1):
   turtle.pendown()
   turtle.right(40)
   turtle.forward(i)
   turtle.begin_fill()
   turtle.color(random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
   turtle.circle(n2-20)
   turtle.end_fill()
   turtle.penup()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle
import random

num    = int(input("How many circles? "))
radius = int(input("Radius? "))

# move to starting point - tangent to right edge of largest circle
turtle.forward(radius)
turtle.left(90)

# draw circles, largest to smallest
for circle in range(num, 0, -1):    # (num .. 1)
    # draw a filled circle
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.color(random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
    turtle.circle(radius * circle / num)
    turtle.end_fill()
    # shift inward to next circle starting-point
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(radius / num)
    turtle.right(90)
```

given 6, 120 produces

[image]